# Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an app where users can create recipes, see all recipes created, view their own recipes in a member area and finally i would like for users to add "favorites" to their account.

I am new to Rails but have read through docs and this is my understanding of what it should look like in the backend. Could someone confirm that this looks correct or advise of any errors please, with explanations if I have done something wrong (which is probably the case)?

So this is my code:

User Model

```
has_many :recipes
has_many_favorites, :through => :recipes
```

Recipe Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :ingredients #created seperate db for ingredients
has_many :prepererations #created seperate db for prep steps
```

Favorite Model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :recipes, :through => :user
#this model has one column for the FK, :user_id
```

Favorites Controller

```
def create
  @favrecipes =current_user.favorites.create(params[:user_id])
end
```

I then wanted to have a button to post to the db, so I have this:

```
<%= button_to("Add to Favorites" :action => "create", :controller => "favorites" %>
```

I think I am probably missing something in my routes but I am unsure.

Answer (score 72):

The particular setup you describe mixes several types of associations.

#### A) User and Recipe

First we have a User model and second a Recipe model. Each recipe belonging to one user, hence we have a User :has_many recipes, Recipe belongs_to :user association. This relationship is stored in the recipe's user_id field.

```
$ rails g model Recipe user_id:integer ...
$ rails g model User ...

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes
end
```

#### B) FavoriteRecipe

Next we need to decide on how to implement the story that a user should be able to mark favorite recipes.

This can be done by using a join model - let's call it FavoriteRecipe - with the columns :user_id and :recipe_id. The association we're building here is a **has_many :through** association.

```
A User  
  - has_many :favorite_recipes  
  - has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :recipe

A Recipe
  - has_many :favorite_recipes  
  - has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :user 
      # returns the users that favorite a recipe
```

Adding this favorites has_many :through association to the models, we get our final results.

```
$ rails g model FavoriteRecipe recipe_id:integer user_id:integer

# Join model connecting user and favorites
class FavoriteRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end

---

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes

  # Favorite recipes of user
  has_many :favorite_recipes # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :recipe # the actual recipes a user favorites
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # Favorited by users
  has_many :favorite_recipes # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :user # the actual users favoriting a recipe
end
```

#### C) Interacting with the associations

```
##
# Association "A"

# Find recipes the current_user created
current_user.recipes

# Create recipe for current_user
current_user.recipes.create!(...)

# Load user that created a recipe
@recipe = Recipe.find(1)
@recipe.user

##
#  Association "B"

# Find favorites for current_user
current_user.favorites

# Find which users favorite @recipe
@recipe = Recipe.find(1)
@recipe.favorited_by # Retrieves users that have favorited this recipe

# Add an existing recipe to current_user's favorites
@recipe = Recipe.find(1)
current_user.favorites << @recipe

# Remove a recipe from current_user's favorites
@recipe = Recipe.find(1)
current_user.favorites.delete(@recipe)  # (Validate)
```

#### D) Controller Actions

There may be several approaches on how to implement Controller actions and routing. I quite like the one by Ryan Bates shown in [Railscast #364](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) on the ActiveRecord Reputation System. The part of a solution described below is structured along the lines of the voting up and down mechanism there.

In our Routes file we add a member route on recipes called favorite. It should respond to post requests. This will add a favorite_recipe_path(@recipe) url helper for our view.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :recipes do
  put :favorite, on: :member
end
```

In our RecipesController we can now add the corresponding favorite action. In there we need to determine what the user wants to do, favoriting or unfavoriting. For this a request parameter called e.g. type can be introduced, that we'll have to pass into our link helper later too.

```
class RecipesController < ...

  # Add and remove favorite recipes
  # for current_user
  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @recipe
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@recipe.name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@recipe)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@recipe.name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end

end
```

In your view you can then add the respective links to favoriting and unfavoriting recipes.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_recipe_path(@recipe, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_recipe_path(@recipe, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

That's it. If a user clicks on the "favorite" link next to a recipe, this recipe is added to the current_user's favorites.

The [**Rails guides on associations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) are pretty comprehensives and will help you a lot when getting started.

Comment: thank you thomas, could you explain why this works? I appreciate it may take a bit of time but it would really help me understand, and give me direction for further reading

Comment: FavoriteRecipe is a join table and essentially all it's doing is establishing a many to many relationship between Recipe and User which is all you really need.

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas, I will read thoroughly tomorrow, any questions I will ask and I'll read the rails guide until it sinks in, thank you again

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have been reading through your explanation and am a little thrown by the naming conventions of :favorited_by and :favorites, I'm confused as the db is called favoriterecipes with two columns, the user_id and the recipe_id. are you able to clarify please?

Comment: As @CyleHunter states correctly "FavoriteRecipe is a join table and essentially all it's doing is establishing a many to many relationship between Recipe and User". Try to create a small little app with for example an `Author` model and a `Book` model and try to link them together in a way that a book has many and belongs to many authors, and an author has many and belongs to many books. This is called a many-to-many relationship. The [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) are quite extensive on this subject, so just try a little when you find the time.

Comment: I understand the relationships now, well more than yesterday anyway. What i dont understand is has_many :favorited_by. Where is Favorited_by defined? its not in the DB? appreciate your help

Comment: also, whoch controller will association b go into? the recipe controller or do i create a specific controller for favouriterecipe?

Comment: You're actually right, in order to rename `users` to `favorited_by` there has to be `:source => :user` attribute set. I updated the code above.

Comment: Hello, so I tried to follow this tutorial of sorts, and I have run into an error I cant seem to solve. Obviously the difference in mine is that I am running rails 4. I thought you might be able to help as this is what I followed, my question is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354507/rails-setting-up-favorites-between-two-models

Comment: Uhm... I had to add `source: :recipe` in my user model for this to work.

Comment: @gosukiwi Thanks, I've added the `source: :recipe` to the answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of `source: :recipe` in `has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :recipe`? Why is it (`source: :recipe`) specified under the `User` model in the first code snippet of Part B but not the second code snippet? Also, why do we not need to write `class_name: Recipe`, e.g. ``has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, class_name: 'Recipe', foreign_key: favorited_by_id' source: :recipe` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the guide, Thomas! It works great.

Just wanted to add that in order for your favorite method to work correctly you need to wrap the text in double quotes instead of single quotes for the string interpolation to function.

```
redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@recipe.name}'
```

->

```
redirect_to :back, notice: "You favorited #{@recipe.name}"
```

https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics

Answer (score 0):

This thread was super helpful!!

Thank you!

Don't forget to include the **=** in the form tags.

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%=link_to "favorite",   favorite_recipe_path(@recipe, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
  <%=link_to "unfavorite", favorite_recipe_path(@recipe, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer is really good however I can't post a comment and I really do have an question about above. How can you limit a user to have one favourite recipe? With the above answer a user can continue pressing favorite and many entries will be created in the database...

Comment: This would be better placed as a comment as this is not an answer. To limit the number of favourites you could have a before filter that checks the users favourites count and then either add that favourite it show a validation message to say limit reached? Just an idea

Comment: Yes I know it should have been a comment therefore my first line there, I am not on 50 reputation yet so sorry. Managed to fix it by using the associations down to the .favorites.ids and then .include?(@recipe.id).

Comment: Apologies, must have missed that first line 