# has_many and belongs_to of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am pretty new to rails. I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to create a relationship between two models that states:

1. A user can "favorite" many songs
2. A song has an owner.

This is what I am thinking of doing. Does it make sense ?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :songs #songs this user has favorited
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user #the user whom submitted this song
end
```

My concern about this method is that I'm unsure about the efficiency of doing query on every song in the database just to figure out which songs a particular user owns. Is there a different way I should be thinking about this ?

By the way, is there a method by which I can call the attribute something different than it's model name. So rather than `User.find(1).songs[0]` I could say `User.find(1).favorites[0]` even though the model is still a "Song".

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3/13240439#13240439) here describes a similar setup you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need 2 separate relationships between the User and Song models.  Namely, you'll need an 'owner' relationship and a 'favorite' relationship.  The 'owner' relationship can be a simple has_many/belongs_to as you have it now.  The 'favorite' relationship is many-to-many and will need a join table used either as a `habtm` table or a first class model with a `has_many through` relationship as explained [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Many-to-many).

The generallly recommended approach is to use `has_many through` as it gives you better control:

```
class User
  has_many :songs                                            # these are songs 'owned' by the user
  has_many :user_favorite_songs
  has_many :favorite_songs, :through => :user_favorite_songs # these are the favorites
end

class Song
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_favorite_songs
end

class UserFavoriteSong
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorite_song, :class_name => 'Song', :foreign_key => :song_id
end
```

Comment: This makes sense, but why does User have many user_favorite_songs AND favorite_songs ? Shouldn't you just need one ?

Comment: `user_favorite_songs` is the association with the join model UserFavoriteSong (which connects a user and a song), while `favorite_songs` is the association for the join model's song which has been named `favorite_song` for clarity.  Ideally, you are trying to link to just `favorite_songs`, but the `has_many through` many-to-many technique requires using a join model association to accomplish this.  A benefit of using this technique would be where a favorite song has properties not specific to a song itself - for example the user's own rating, or order sequence.

Comment: That makes sense. If I wanted to have some specific property to belong to a favorite then this would be another advantage. Even knowing the datetime that the user favorited the song could be useful later on. Thanks Pinny.

Comment: Why do we not need to write `class_name: Song` and `foreign_key:user_favorite_songs_id` or something similar in the line `has_many :favorite_songs` under the `User` model, e.g. `has_many :favorite_songs, through: :user_favorite_songs, class_name: 'Song', foreign_key: :user_favorite_songs_id`?

How does rails know that `:favorite_songs` refer to `Song`?

Comment: Since this is a `has_many through:` relationship, ActiveRecord can figure that out by inspecting the specified relationship that resides in the `UserFavoriteSong` model.  No need to be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

This looks perfectly fine.
Rails associations try to be most efficient - don't prematurely optimize.

You can alias the association's name like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites, class_name: 'Song'
end
```

see the [docs about associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).

Regarding performance anyway, you might want to have a look at the `:inverse_of` association option.

Comment: I agree -- it's sometimes not worth over-thinking it. Your answer works perfectly fine in the case where we aren't as concerned about optimization.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this code, but you'll need something like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :favorites, :class_name => "Song" #user's favorited songs
end

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #the user who submitted the song
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user, :as => :favorite
end
```

And since multiple users can favorite a song, you'll need a 'join table'

```
CreateUsersFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users_favorites do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :favorite
    end
    create_index :users_favorites, :user_id
    create_index :users_favorites, :favorite_id
  end
  def down
    drop_table :users_favorites
  end
end
```

Also, I highly recommend taking a look at the [rails guide for active record relationships](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).