# Rails Model Association: Favoriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to follow this post on adding favorites to my Rails app: [Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3)

In my app, I'd like users to be able to favorite projects.  Right now, when I try to implement a link_to the favorites action in the project controller, I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in ProjectsController#favorite
Could not find the source association(s) :favorite or :favorites in model FavoriteProject.
Try 'has_many :favorites, :through => :favorite_projects, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :project or :user?
```

How can I fix this error?

**favorite_project.rb:**

```
class FavoriteProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, :avatar
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy

  # Favorite projects
  has_many :favorite_projects # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, :through => :favorite_projects # projects a user favorites

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  validates :username, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true
end
```

**project.rb:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :images_attributes, :ancestry, :user_id
  has_many :steps, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :user

   # Favorited by users
  has_many :favorite_projects
  has_many :favorited_by, :through => :favorite_projects, :source => :user # users that favorite a project

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

  validates :title, :presence => true
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
 def favorite
    current_user.favorites << @project
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Build::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => :registrations}
  get "home/index"

  resources :users do
     match 'users/:id' => 'users#username'
  end

  resources :projects do
     collection {post :sort}
     get :editTitle, on: :collection
     put :favorite, on: :member
    resources :steps do
        collection {post :sort}
        get :create_branch_a, on: :collection
        get :create_branch_b, on: :collection
        get :update_ancestry, on: :collection
        get :edit_redirect, on: :collection
        get :show_redirect, on: :collection
      end
      match "steps/:id" => "steps#number", :as => :number
  end

  resources :images do
     collection {post :sort}
   end

  root :to => 'home#index'

  post "versions/:id/revert" => "versions#revert", :as => "revert_version"

end
```

**index.html.erb view file:**

```
 <%= link_to "", favorite_project_path(@project), method: :put, :class=> "icon-star-empty favoriteStar", :title=> "Favorite", :rel=>"tooltip" %>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving current_user after you add `@project`?

Comment: I'm not sure why I would need to do that.  Can you explain further?

Comment: Try this in the console and see what output you get. I'm not sure that saving is the right answer here, depends on how you're creating `@project` in the controller.  Also, check what @Babur said below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
has_many :favorites, :through => :favorite_projects
```

But there is no `favorites` association in `FavoriteProject` model. Only `belongs_to :project`. It should be:

```
has_many :favorites, :through => :favorite_projects, :source => :project
```

Comment: thanks!  I also had an additional error in that "@project" wasn't defined in my controller.  I added the following line to my favorite action:  @project = Project.find(params[:id])