# Rails Favorites Model Association, link_to not producing html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I am trying to implement a favorite relationship in my Ruby on Rails app. The route, controller, and relationship all appear to be working but link_to "favorite" is not working, by which I mean it is not even producing the html link, though it is throwing no error. I am following the example here [Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3).

Here is the code:

routes.rb

```
resources :locations do
  put :favorite, on: :member
end
```

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  ....
  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @location
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@location.name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@location)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@location.name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ....
   # Favorite locations of user
   has_many :favorite_locations # just the 'relationships'
   has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_locations # the actual recipes a user favorites
   ....
 end
```

location.rb

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  # Favorited by users
  has_many :favorite_locations # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_locations, source: :user
end
```

view/locations/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @location.name) %>

....
<% link_to "favorite", favorite_location_path(@location, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
<% link_to "unfavorite", favorite_location_path(@location, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot the = in the <% %>, should be:

```
<%= link_to "favorite", favorite_location_path(@location, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
```

Comment: This was the issue thank you, I am still getting used to erb syntax.