# Tracking User's Liked Events in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

I'm looking to incorporate a button to where users can click it and add an event to their list of events. The events they added to their list will then be populated on another view.

I'm wondering what the best way to implement this is.

I've considered using a serialized text column in my table and just pushing the event's id to the array. Is the best way of going about doing this and do I still have functionality to operate on the array?

Comment: Rather than storing ids in a serialized text column, consider a basic `has_many :through` association (which is more flexible than `has_and_belongs_to`). You can [adapt this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3/13240439#13240439) for your own needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is associations, specifically the has_and_belongs_to_many association.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I remember having the exact same thought as you when I was starting out - use a column in the model to act as a bucket which stores all the IDs of another model. While this is technically possible using serialize, it's not at all ideal as searching through a serialized column is extremely inefficient. PostgreSQL has the hstore data type which would greatly speed up searching, but it's still not ideal.

Associations in Rails are worked right into the framework and learning how to use them is vital to your future success as a rails developer. That guide will explain it better than I ever could. If you're getting stuck, I'd start out by doing a simple has_many and belongs_to relationship between Users and Events in a playground application. Then implement has_and_belongs_to_many in your production app.

Comment: I had come across associations but wasn't sure where to start and if it was best for what I was trying to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem. If you run into trouble, I'd be happy to make a little sample app and upload it to github. Associations are easy once you get the hang of it!

Comment: Users can post their own Events to the site but also "like" other Events to add to their schedule/calendar. There is already a belongs_to and has_many relationship between the two for their own Events. Is there a way to add another association between Users and liked Events without creating another model specifically for these? I'm sure there is but there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Actually, after looking at the comment under my initial post, has_many :through looks to be what I'm looking for!