# User to mark (favorite-like) another Model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, favorites

I want to implement a "Read Later" (just like Favorites) system in a Ruby on Rails app. What I want is for a `User` model to be able to mark a `Content` model to read later.

My associations between the two models are like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents
end

-------------

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Then a Content belongs to a `Category`, etc, but that doesn't matter for the question so I just didn't put it there.

A `User` can mark a `Content` (that could belong to another user) and there will be a list of "marked contents (to read later)" for each user.

How could I implement this?

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3) question but I didn't really understand and when trying to simulate it, it didn't work.

Comment: The answer you link to is actually great, so please try to understand it and apply it.

Comment: @nathanvda It is, but with the code just like that it shows me an error about the `:source`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you try and what didn't work?

This is pretty straight forward. Let us think through:

There is a User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

There is Content:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

A User can create Content and is he restricted to create only one content? no. A User can create as many contents as he wants. This is to say in Rails terms a User `has_many` contents. To put this in other words, can we say that a Content is created by a User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecored::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, the content (typically created by other users) can be favorited (marked as 'Read Later') by other users. Each User can favorite (mark 'Read Later') as many contents as he wants and each Content can be favorited by many users isn't it? However, we'll have to track which User favorited which Content somewhere. The easiest would be to define another model, let us say MarkedContent, to hold this information. A has_many :through association is often used to set up a many-to-many connection with another model. So the relevant association declarations could look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents

  has_many :marked_contents
  has_many :markings, through: :marked_contents, source: :content
end

class MarkedContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :content
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :marked_contents
  has_many :marked_by, through: :marked_contents, source: :user
end
```

Now you can do:

```
user.contents # to get all the content created by this user
user.marked_contents # to get all the contents marked as 'Read Later' by this user

content.user # to get the creator of this content
content.marked_by # to get all the users who have marked this content
```

Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to learn about associations.

To mark a content as a favorite, one way would be:

```
@user = User.first
@content = Content.last

@user.markings << @content
```

You can also implement a method in the User model to do this for you:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def read_later(content)
    markings << content
  end
end
```

Now, you can do:

```
@user.read_later(@content)
```

Comment: To use `has_many :markings` and `has_many :marked_by` he would need to specify the appropriate class name on the associations

Comment: I don't think I understood what you said, @Baloo. Could you be more specific?

Comment: By having `has_many :marked_by, through: :marked_contents` rails will try to find the class MarkedBy, if you want to use that rather than `, has_many :users, through: :marked_contents` you will need to use `has_many :marked_by,  class_name: 'User', through: :marked_contents` and the same sort of thing with `has_many :markings`

Comment: From what I understand, I have to create a Model `MarkedContent`, right? With no attributes? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: @Baloo fixed the associations, thanks. You'll have to specify the source option in order for this to work.

Comment: @gd.silva No, you'll have to create MarkedContent with user_id, content_id as attributes, wherein each record will tell, which content (content_id) is marked by which user (user_id).

Comment: Alright, I think I understood. But now how do I mark a content with a user?

Comment: Thanks. I've created a route and a controller action and it seems to work! But now I have to be able to do the opposite action, delete a content from marked to read later. How do I do that? And it's possible do add more than one row with the same (content_id, user_id) to the table, how could I prevent that? Using add_index? I'm no expert in this matters.

Comment: @SyedAslam And whats does `<<` mean in `markings << content`? It looks like "add". If it is, how to do the opposite?

Comment: Yes, << is similar to the 'add' method. To delete only the the association you'll have to do: @user.markings.destroy (@content)

Comment: Thank you, @SyedAslam. And how do I prevent that a user can "mark" the same content more than once? It creates doubles.

Comment: @gd.silva you're welcome. You'll have to put a uniqueness constraint in MarkedContent model something in the lines of: validates :content_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :user_id }