# A better way to set up routes? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Is there a better way to setup these two routes below:

```
 post '/song:id/favorite', to: 'songs#favorite', as: :favorite
  delete '/song:id/favorite', to: 'favorites#destroy', as: :destroy
```

Here are all of my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "home#index"
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

  post '/song:id/favorite', to: 'songs#favorite', as: :favorite
  delete '/song:id/favorite', to: 'favorites#destroy', as: :destroy

  namespace :admin do
    resource :dashboard, only: [:show]
  end

  resources :users, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :playlists
  resources :genres
  resources :albums
  resources :artists
  resources :playlist_songs
  resources :favorites
  resources :songs

end
```

Comment: It seems to me you could try to implement something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24306086/6873497). I think your current design   could be tweaked to use simple CRUD actions.

Comment: Thanks @matiss! My design is created as per you advice already :) My question basically is , is there something wrong how my current routes are set or is there is a better way to do it? p.s I'm a rookie

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
resources :songs do
  member do
    post   'favorite', to: 'songs#favorite',    as: :favorite
    delete 'favorite', to: 'favorites#destroy', as: :destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

These actions don't really belong to the songs controller. Thinking about it, it's not doing a CRUD action for a song (you don't create, edit or delete a song).

I would use a concept called Nested Resources (http://blog.8thcolor.com/en/2011/08/nested-resources-with-independent-views-in-ruby-on-rails/ -- this is a great intro).

Basically, I would structure my routes as:

```
resources :songs do
  resources :favourites, only: [:create, destroy]
end
```

Comment: Thanks Cionescu..but my songs#favorite is songs controller, and destroy is in favorites controller. You are saying I sholud put them all in favorites controller and then, rearrange my routes as per your structure? btw. I'm using ajax to make song as a favorite. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's my suggestion. Ajax shouldn't be a problem. You could also use Rails' UJS which will work nicely with the route helpers