# Rails 4 has_many :through association with :source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I was following the answer laid out at the link below to set up a many_to_many relationships on my Rails 4 app. (New to rails, here.)
[Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4)

I have Users and Exercises, and I want users to be able to have Favorite Exercises. I created a join table called FavoriteExercise with user_id and exercise_id as columns. I've got it populating, and it seems to be working fine, but I'm not able to use it to call directly to my favorites.

Meaning, I want to type:
**user.favorite** = #list of exercises that have been favorited

I get this error when I try to load that list in my browser:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: exercises.favorite_exercise_id: 

SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" INNER JOIN "favorite_exercises" 
ON "exercises"."favorite_exercise_id" = "favorite_exercises"."id"
WHERE > "favorite_exercises"."user_id" = ?
```

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts    
  has_many :exercises   
  has_many :favorite_exercises
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_exercises, source: :exercises

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :workouts, :through => :exercises_workouts
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_exercises, source: :exercises

class FavoriteExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercises
  has_many :users
```

I just tried switching FavoriteExercise to 'belongs_to' instead of 'has_many, because it seems maybe that's the way that should go? but then I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant User::Exercises
```

Just trying to figure out how to set up the tables and associations so I can call .favorites on a user and get all their favorites.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simplify your model logic as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
  has_many :exercises     
  has_many :favorite_exercises
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_exercises, class_name: "Exercise"

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :workouts, :through => :exercises_workouts
  has_many :favorite_exercises
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_exercises, class_name: "User"

class FavoriteExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :favorited_by
  belongs_to :favorite
```

Then you can call `user.excercises` or `excercise.users` in your User/Excercise instance.

`user.excercises` = #list of exercises that have been favorited

Is that the many-to-many relationship you want?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to be able to have both of the following:

```user.exercises = # all exercises the user has created``` and  
```user.favorites = # all exercises favorited by the user```

which is why i had ```has_many :exercises``` separate from ```has_many :favorites ```

Comment: I changed the code to match what you put in. ```users.exercises``` returns exercises which have the user_id associated with my user, not the exercises from the FavoriteExercises table that have my user_id associated

Comment: and I still get the same SQL error from ```user.favorites```

Comment: Same SQL error, even with the class designation moved to the new spot. I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of exercises of the user and at the same, the list of favorite exercise of the user, then I think your join table should just be users_exercises wherein it will list all the exercises by the users. To list the favorite exercises, just add a boolean field indicating if the exercise is a user favorite and add a :scope to get all the favorite exercises.

So in your migration file:

`users_exercises` should have `user_id, exercise_id, is_favorite`

Then in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts    
  has_many :users_exercises
  has_many :exercises, through: :users_exercises

  scope :favorite_exercises, -> {
    joins(:users_exercises).
    where("users_exercises.is_favorite = ?", true)
  }

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts, :through => :exercises_workouts
  has_many :users_exercises
  has_many :users, through: :users_exercises

class UsersExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Does this allow users to favorite exercises other than their own? (I haven't used scope before, so I'm reading the docs.)

Comment: No, it will not allow the user to favorite exercise other than their own. But if you want that to happen, then maybe just add another join table users_favorite_exercises aside for users_exercises. :)