# How to add new element to array via link_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Exercise and User model. User can share his exercises with each other through SharedExercise model. Exercise may be public or private, and users are allowed to add public exercises to their private exercises. I need to add simple link/button to do this, but have no idea how.

Im looking for something like:

```
def add
  @exercise = Exercise.find(params[:id])
  current_user.exercises << @exercise
end
```

but how to pass that to link/button?

Comment: This is a controller method. Links should be in views. It is very unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Your problem seems to be somewhat similar to [Implement add to favorites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4) - you can study the proposed implementation and infer from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Exercises Controller You could get array of users who have already been assigned to this exercise and add current_user to this array with next updating of this exercise...

Something like that:

```
def add_user
@exercise = Exercise.includes(:user_ids).where(id: params[:id])
@user_ids = @exercise.user_ids
!@user_ids.index(params[:user][:id]) && @exercise.user_ids = @user_ids.push(params[:user][:id])
...
if @exercise.update_attributes(@user_ids)
  redirect_to ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it was not exactly what I was looking for, but it helped me to find the right way!