# Rails: Favorite Model working but favorite/unfavorite links not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favorites

I followed the steps from the first answer posted by Thomas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4)

I can go into Heroku Console and manually favorite phootos by users so the models are setup correctly and working but my favorite/unfavorite links are not working.

```
<p><strong>Picture:</strong></p> 
<%= image_tag(@phooto.picture) %>

<%= link_to("< Previous", @phooto.previous) if @phooto.previous %>
<%= link_to("Next >", @phooto.next) if @phooto.next %>

<% if current_user %>
<%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_phooto_path(@phooto, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_phooto_path(@phooto, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

Heroku Log

```
Started PUT "/phootos/24/favorite?type=favorite"
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Phooto(#70057240967940) expected, got NilClass(#70057199933300)):
app/controllers/phootos_controller.rb:29:in `favorite
```

PhootosController

```
def show
  @phooto = Phooto.find(params[:id])
end

def favorite  
  type = params[:type]
  if type == "favorite"
    **rb.29** current_user.favorites << @phooto
              redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully favorited #{@phooto.name}'

  elsif type == "unfavorite"
    current_user.favorites.delete(@phooto)
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited #{@phooto.name}'

  else
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
  end    
end
```

Phootos/show.html.erb

```
<p><strong>Picture:</strong></p> 
<%= image_tag(@phooto.picture) %>
<%= link_to("< Previous", @phooto.previous) if @phooto.previous %>
<%= link_to("Next >", @phooto.next) if @phooto.next %>

<% if current_user %>
<%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_phooto_path(@phooto, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_phooto_path(@phooto, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users
resources :phootos
resources :phootos do
  put :favorite, on: :member
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line as your first line in your `favorite` method in `PhootosController`

```
@phooto = Phooto.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, a better pattern for this will be to match the `favorite` route based on its [HTTP verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users
resources :phootos do
   match :favorite, on: :member, via: [:put, :delete]
end
```

This will do away with the `type` argument in your path (which is causing issues):

```
<% if current_user %>
   <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_phooto_path(@phooto), method: :put %>
   <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_phooto_path(@phooto), method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

You'll have to change your controller to handle the requests & variable:

```
def favorite
  @phooto = Phooto.find params[:id]

  if request.put?
      current_user.favorites << @phooto
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully favorited #{@phooto.name}'
  elsif request.delete?
      current_user.favorites.delete(@phooto)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You successfully unfavorited #{@phooto.name}'
  else
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
  end    
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much this looks more efficient.

Comment: @Richard Peck can you please see this topic... stackoverflow.com/questions/38027265/… and answer if possible thank you

Comment: @RichardPeck can you please see this topic... stackoverflow.com/questions/38027265/… and answer if possible thank you