# Implement add Recipe to favorites in Rails and find if current user has 'favorite_set?' a recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many-through

This question is related [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4/13240439#13240439) that shows a **has_many :through association**. I have a similar association as shown in the answer. I will cite for reference.

> 

```
$ rails g model FavoriteRecipe recipe_id:integer user_id:integer

# Join model connecting user and favorites
class FavoriteRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end

---

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes

  # Favorite recipes of user
  has_many :favorite_recipes # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :recipe # the actual recipes a user favorites
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # Favorited by users
  has_many :favorite_recipes # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :user # the actual users favoriting a recipe
end
```

I am curious to know if this solution would work with a many-to-many relationship with joining model e.g. `FavoriteRecipe` that has a boolean attribute `favorite_set`. When iterating through the `Recipes` I would like to find out if the current user has 'favorited' this/these `Recipes`. Something like `current_user.recipe.favorite_set?` but of course going through the `FavoriteRecipe` joining model. If `true` display 'FAVORITE SET' otherwise give an option to favorite this `recipe`. My implementation is a feed that displays all "Recipes" and shows "FAVORITE SET" or gives the option to "favorite" one or multiple `Recipes`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you can add attributes to `FavoriteRecipe` - it's just a model. But I don't think you want to complicate things by adding some kind of boolean when you can do it with count query. To check if the user has any favorites you would do `user.favorite_recipes.any?` to check if he has favorited a specific recipe the easiest way is: `FavoriteRecipe.where(user: user, recipe: recipe).any?` or `user.favorite_recipes.where(recipe: recipe).any?`

Comment: @max thanks for the suggestion. I think this could work. In a controller I can get the current user `@favorites= current_user.favorite_recipes.any?` and `@recipes = FavoriteRecipe.all` and In my view  iterate through both `@favorites` and `recipes` and do a comparison or determine if the `current_user` has "favorited" this `recipe`. I think the other queries are expensive to do inside an `each` loop in my view.  Is this somewhat close to what you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I created a helper module in `app/helpers`

```
module ReminderHelper
  #Check if user has set reminder for a specific event
  def event_reminder_set? user, event
    EventReminder.where(user: user, event: event).any?
  end 
end
```

I included the module in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
include ReminderHelper
```

In my view I use it as follows

```
<% unless event_reminder_set?(current_or_guest_user, event) %>
    REMIND ME
<% else %>
    REMINDER SET
<% end %>
```

This should work with other models associations with a many-to-many relationship with joining model e.g. `FavoriteRecipe`

Comment: It should be like `user.event_reminders.where(event: event).any?`. Helper is for simplifying the views. You don't have to include it in the controller. Thanks