# Rails: Set up favorite recipe for user but keep getting same error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As a user I want to be able to add a recipe to my Favorites. Unfortunately when I try to add a recipe to my Favorites I get the following `error: Recipe(#69883866963220) expected, got NilClass(#46922250887180)`.

I followed this ['tutorial'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4) as a guideline

Somehow it is not able to add it to the user's Favorites. When I use `Rails C` and type in `User.find(1).favorites`, it returns me an empty array.

Who can help me to solve the issue? Thank you in advance!

**My models:**

```
class FavoriteRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipes

  # Favorite recipes of user
  has_many :favorite_recipes # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :recipe # the actual recipes a user favorites
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # Favorited by users
  has_many :favorite_recipes # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :user # the actual users favoriting a recipe
end
```

**My recipecontroller.rb:**

```
def show
    @review = Review.new
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@recipe.user_id)
    @full_name = @recipe.user.first_name + " " + @recipe.user.last_name
    # @reviews = @recipe.reviews.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  # Add and remove favorite recipes
  # for current_user
  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @recipe
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@recipe.name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@recipe)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@recipe.name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :recipes, only: [:index, :show] do
    put :favorite, on: :member
end
```

**My view: app/views/recipes/show.html.erb**

```
  <% if current_user.favorites.exists?(id: @recipe.id) %>
    <%= link_to favorite_recipe_path(@recipe, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put do %>
      <ul class="list-inline product-controls">
        <li><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to favorite_recipe_path(@recipe, type: "favorite"), method: :put do %>
      <ul class="list-inline product-controls">
        <li><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your relationship you need recipe object to assign to user. So need to first find that object and then assign it to user.

```
def favorite
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @recipe
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@recipe.name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@recipe)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@recipe.name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I missed that.