# Implement "add to favorites"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, favorite

I am creating an app where a user can favorite a room. I started with a has_and_belongs_to_many association. But then I just noticed that it is very tricky to implement a remove button with drestroy. So I decided to do it this time with a has_many through association. I have a users who should add rooms to favorite or wishlist. Unfortunately when I click on the favorite button I am getting this error:

[image]

**What I am missing how can I make this work?**

If you need further information just let me know. I have used this as a direction.

[Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4)

**favorite_room.rb**

```
class FavoriteRoom < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :room
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**room.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :favorite_rooms  
has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_rooms, source: :user
```

**user.rb**

```
 has_many :rooms
 has_many :favorite_rooms 
 has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_rooms, source: :room
```

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :rooms do
    put :favorite, on: :member
 end
```

**rooms_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :favorite]
...
...
def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @room
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'You favorited #{@room.listing_name}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@room)
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@room.listing_name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to wishlist_path, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
end

private
def set_room
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_room_path(@room, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_room_path(@room, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

**create_favorite_rooms.rb (migration file)**

```
class CreateFavoriteRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :favorite_rooms do |t|
      t.integer :room_id
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is `@room` being set?  In a `before_action`?

Comment: I was so blind! I have added @room in the before action but I am getting now a different error message...  ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in RoomsController#favorite, Validation failed: User must exist same line as previously... I have eddited my question! Thank you!

Comment: can you add your migration file that creates the `favorite_rooms` table?

Comment: Sure I have added it into my question ;)

Comment: It should be `current_user.favorite_rooms << @room`

Comment: Thank you for trying but I get then the error from this line: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RoomsController#favorite - FavoriteRoom(#70224656935980) expected, got Room(#70224659838060) - current_user.favorite_rooms << @room

Comment: your associations look good to me :/ have you run migrations after you changed your approach from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many through`? check your `schema.rb`

Comment: please check if `@room` has `user_id` value in it?

Comment: your @room object is invalid... you must have some validation in the Room model that says `validates :user, presence: true` is that correct?  The room's user must have been deleted at some point.  Try this in the console...`room = Room.find((whatever ID you're trying to use)`  and then `room.save` and I bet it won't save.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn You are right I can't save it as a user! Thanks allot! I create rooms with active admin... I created the association between user and room because I wanted to make it work with favorite action. How can I make this work? And no I don't have any validations in the room model only for geocode gem.

Comment: @gabrielhilal the schema.rb file looks fine but thanks! ;)

Comment: just take out from `room` the `belongs_to :user` and it should work (or at least get further along in your development)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn worked perfectly thanks allot!!!