# Rails 5 favourite mechanism

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im building a ToDo app, since Im new with Ruby, and I want that users can favourite lists of Todos. The app has two kind of lists: public and private, so if the user is not logged in he will be able to see public lists, but wont be able to favourite them (obviously).

I followed this tutorial: [Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4) but Im getting and error in my controllers saying that uninitialized constant User::FavouriteList when I try to (un)favourite the list. Im not sure how Im doing wrong, since it seems that solution worked for everyone. Here are my codes:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_list, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @lists = List.all
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
    @list.todos.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @list = current_user.lists.new list_params
    @list.todos.each do |todo|
      todo.user_id = current_user.id
    end

    if @list.save

        redirect_to @list, notice: "List was successfuly created!"
    else
        render action: :new
    end
  end

  def update

    @list.close = true
    @list.todos.each do |todo|
      if !todo.close
        @list.close = false
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.update(list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: "List was successfuly updated!" }
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @list }
        else
        format.html {render :edit }
        format.json {render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list.destroy
    redirect_to lists_url, notice: "List was successfuly removed!"
  end

  def favourite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favourite"
      current_user.favourites << @list
      redirect_to :back
    elsif type == "unfavourite"
      current_user.favourites.delete(@list)
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Nothing happened."
    end
  end


  private

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:title, :public, :close, todos_attributes: Todo.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy))
  end

end

class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :todos, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favourite_lists
  has_many :favourites, through: :favourite_lists, source: :list


  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :confirmable
end

class List < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :favourite_lists
    has_many :favourites, through: :favourite_lists, source: :user
    has_many :todos, inverse_of: :list, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |att| att['task'].blank? } 

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates_associated :todos
end

class Favourite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_id
  belongs_to :list_id
end
```

View and its partial

```
<h1>Public Lists</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Favourites</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Created at</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% @lists.each do |list| %>
                    <% if list.public %>
                        <tr>
                            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                                <td><%= render "favourites", object: list %></td>
                            <% end %>
                            <td><%= list.title %></td>
                            <td><%= @users.find(list.user_id).name %></td>
                            <td><%= list.created_at %></td>
                            <td><%= link_to "View", show_list_path(list), class: "btn btn-primary", role: "btn" %></td>
                            <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.id == list.user_id %>
                                <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_list_path(list), class: "btn btn-default", role: "btn" %></td>
                                <%= render "delete_button", path: list %>
                            <% end %>
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Partial with fav buttons

```
<td><%= link_to "aaaaa", favourite_list_path(object, type: "unfavourite"), method: :put %><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>

<td><%= link_to "aaaaaaaa", favourite_list_path(object, type: "favourite"), method: :put %><i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
```

Comment: may you show code of related models?

Comment: They are there above the controller

Comment: Often error like `uninitialized constant User::FavouriteList` happens when you call `FavouriteList` inside User model and FavouriteList class does not exist

Comment: My friend suggested me to create a users_lists table, although Im not sure if that is the case. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Model name. Even with all relationships set, the model needed to be called FavouriteLists instead of Favourites.