# User Favorites - ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

Plenty of questions already exist around this, but none quite solve my issue.

I am trying to implement a feature allowing users to 'favorite' coffeeshops from the answer in this [Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4). But when trying to add the favorite I get:

`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Coffeeshop(#70266474861840) expected, got NilClass(#70266382630600)):`

*user.rb*

```
  has_many :coffeeshops
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :coffeeshop
```

*coffeeshops.rb*

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorite_coffeeshops # just the 'relationships'
  has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_coffeeshops, source: :user
```

New model to join the relationship

*favorite_coffeeshops*

```
class FavoriteCoffeeshop < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :coffeeshop
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*coffeeshops.show.html.erb*

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= link_to "favorite",   favorite_coffeeshop_path(@coffeeshop, type: "favorite"), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "unfavorite", favorite_coffeeshop_path(@coffeeshop, type: "unfavorite"), method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

*coffeeshops_controller.rb*

```
  def favorite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @coffeeshop
      redirect_to :back, notice: "You favorited #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@coffeeshop)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Unfavorited #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Nothing happened."
    end
  end
```

I realise the original question was based on Rails 3/4, and I'm on 5, so maybe something is now outdated in my code.

**Solution**

*coffeeshops_controller.rb*

```
  def favorite
    @coffeeshop = Coffeeshop.find(params[:id]) #<= Added this
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
      current_user.favorites << @coffeeshop
      redirect_to :back, notice: "You favorited #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
      current_user.favorites.delete(@coffeeshop)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Unfavorited #{@coffeeshop.name}"

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Nothing happened."
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@coffeeshop` is null, you should initialize it with the one that the user wants to favorite (e.g retrieving from `params[:id]`)

Comment: The params indicate that @coffeeshop is not null.  I'm using friendly ids gem.

"method"=>"put", "authenticity_token"=>"WufNmDtpYuF1WaBeVuyPYt9cdWAbEw7ieMoHotrKnJ9WUJx0c0PJqvvact8FT+H1LPoxKXC8smQWYCjrzawY0w==", "type"=>"favorite", 
"id"=>"flatplanet"