# Association Type Mismatch Error in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations, type-mismatch

I am working on building a favoriting system in a rails app outlined here [Implement "Add to favorites" in Rails 3 & 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240109/implement-add-to-favorites-in-rails-3-4) however I keep running into the following error.

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RecipesController#favorite
Recipe(#106776840) expected, got nil which is an instance of NilClass(#21446380)

```
type = params[:type]
    if type == "favorite"
     current_user.favorites << @recipe_id
     redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@recipe.title}'

    elsif type == "unfavorite"
```

My code is as follows.

Recipes Model

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :steps, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorite_recipes
    has_many :favorited_by, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :user

    validates :title, presence: true

    def self.search(search)
        where("title LIKE ? OR creator LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%") 
    end
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :favorite_recipes
    has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_recipes, source: :recipe
end
```

Favorite Recipe Model

```
class FavoriteRecipe < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Recipes Controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

    def favorite
        type = params[:type]
        if type == "favorite"
         current_user.favorites << @recipe
         redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favorited #{@recipe.title}'

        elsif type == "unfavorite"
         current_user.favorites.delete(@recipe)
         redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavorited #{@recipe.title}'

        else
            # Type missing, nothing happens
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
        end
    end
end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :recipes do
    resources :ingredients, :steps
    put :favorite, on: :member
  end

  resources :users

end
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: The `@recipe` variable isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by @Зелёный the "@recipe" variable was defined in the controller but needed to be defined as "@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])" in the "favorite" method.